# 401k plan employee rights?

Tags: united-states, 401k, law, privacy

Is it legal for my employer to know what I'm doing with my money that is in the 401k, that comes from my employer, without my consent? Is the financial services company that manages my 401k permitted to report that information to my employer?

Comment: It's certainly legal for them to know. Neither you nor they will be breaking the law if you tell them. Are you asking if they have a _right_ to know, even if it's without your consent?

Comment: If they don't have my consent do they still have the right?

Comment: @webb I've updated the question per your comment - please update further if needed.

Comment: Why do you care if they know? It's not like the fact that you are investing in large-cap versus small-cap or whatever is deeply personal information that you would be embarrassed to have others know, is it? Are they pressuring you to invest in one thing versus another? I'm just wondering what the issue is.

Comment: Cause my boss isn't putting money in my 401k cause I take some of it out , but he's putting it in the other workers 401k, I didnt know if that was right, that he has a right to know what I do with the money, its hard when u get laid of

Comment: If by _"cause I take some of it out"_ you mean you have taken a _loan_ from your 401k plan, then the boss is certainly entitled to know that regardless of how hurt your feelings might be. In some 401k plans, new contributions are prohibited while a loan is outstanding. In others, new "contributions" are used to _pay off_ the loan (plus interest) and so they _are_ being sent to the plan but not showing up as new contributions in your 401k account. If instead, you took a _hardship_ distribution from your 401k, then it might well be that new contributions are prohibited for some time.

Comment: "it[']s hard when u get laid of[f]" ... Are you currently laid off? If so, you're not being paid, so there's no contribution going into your 401K, since it's usually tied to compensation.

Comment: It sounds like this is something you should probably discuss with an attorney.